# Explode in codeigniter not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on an edit function using explode . I inserted some data into db using implode and while edit the checkbox according to the data is appeared as checked but after i done submit (ie,edit) no values are saved in db. this is the code that i'm using

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="#" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Related Packages</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php
            foreach ($selectdata as $r) {
                $t = $r->package_id;
            }
            $explode = explode("','", $t);
            $SlNo = 1;
            foreach ($record as $r2) {
                if (in_array($r2->package_name, $explode)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input id="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++; ?>" type="checkbox"
                                   value="<?php foreach ($explode as $e) {
                                       echo $e;
                                   } ?>" checked="checked">
                            <label for="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++; ?>">
                                <?php echo $r2->package_name; ?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input id="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++; ?>" type="checkbox" name="package[]"
                                   value="<?php echo $r2->package_name; ?>">
                            <label for="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++; ?>">
                                <?php echo $r2->package_name; ?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do var_dump($explode ) and post the result here

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Enchanting North" }

Answer (score 0):

You need implode to create the comma delimited list

```
<input id="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php  echo implode(',',$explode)?>" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 0):

Print your result here therefor we all understand properly,
and initializa your array before storing values into it.

```
$t = array();         
foreach($selectdata as $r)
{
    $t[] = $r->package_id; 
}
$explode =  explode(",",$t);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($explode);
```

if you get array of values in to it then check manually with your record array values.

Comment: actually i getting correct value ie, the checkbox is checked according to the data from db but after i make any changes and submit the value is saving as null

Comment: Then the problem is not in exploding.
do print_r or var dump in your server side insert code.and take name attribute in you first checkbox div.
check your selected values are reaching to server side code or not.

Comment: look this a am getting this as value array(3) { [0]=> string(24) " Kerala Backwater Tours" [1]=> string(18) "Kerala Beach Tours" [2]=> string(16) "Enchanting North" } but after saving this value is not inserting in db

Comment: then there is some mistake in your update query.can we see your server side code or query?

Comment: oh rits i found the error , its my bad i forgot to put name in the if condition, now it works fine.

Comment: Great brother...
wlcm,
if you get solution from my answer or anything please give me upvote. or mark answer as right answer.
thnkx